# Whats the different probabilities in a probability game where last ticket wins, where you can choose to pay for 1 or 2 tickets?

Tags: probability, statistics

Suppose you had a game where each player can pay 1 coin for 1 ticket, or 2 coins for 2 tickets. Every ticket is shuffled in a bowl with each players name written on it. The game works by drawing tickets out of the bowl until there is only 3 tickets left, where each owner of the remaining tickets wins a prize each. If you purchased two tickets and both your tickets are left at the end, you win two prizes.

My question is, how much higher probability is it to win by purchasing two tickets instead of one?

And how does the chance that you can win two prizes affect this?

Comment: This is not clear.  What does "remaining tickets" mean?  The two or three that are left in the bowl?  The ones you bought?   Since it doesn't cost any more (or less)  to buy two tickets at once than it does to buy them one at a time, what difference does it make?

Comment: I am sorry, my english is not the best. With remaining tickets, I mean the 3 tickets that are left after the rest has been drawn. So when the game is over, there are 3 tickets left in the bowl with 3 names on it. Where you could possibly have your name on 2 of them (if you purchased 2). 

Not sure if I understand what you mean with what difference it makes with buying one at a time or not, if you purchase 2 you have two tickets, thus higher chance to win, but also the possibility to win 2 prizes.

Comment: Ok, so:  you purchase tickets to go into the bowl and then, subsequently, tickets are drawn randomly until exactly three are left?  So, instead, you could just choose three tickets from the bowl, right?  The drawing one by one doesn't do anything but reduce the number.  So, then, if I understand correctly, having two tickets in the pile at the beginning more or less doubles your chances of a win.  If you had $1$ out of $N$ your chance of winning would be $\frac 3N$, where if you had $2$ out of $N+1$ your chance of winning (at least one prize) is $1-\binom {N-1}3\big / \binom {N+1}3$.

Comment: Note too that you have a (probably small) chance of doubling the prize, so all the more reason to pay up.  Of course, you don't say what the value of a prize is so if the expected value of a win is less than a coin, you probably shouldn't play at all.

Comment: Thank you very much! And yes, I didn't even realise, but you could in theory just pull out 3 tickets in the beginning. I tried to use the formula you provided, but my results doesn't make sense (I think). Could you help me calculate the chance with an example? I got 0.07 for one ticket and 0.01 for two if total tickets was 40....

Comment: The total number of tickets depends on the number of tickets you buy. Let's say the other players buy $39$ tickets.  then if you buy $1$, the total number is $40$ and your chance of a win is $\frac 3{40}=.075$   If you buy $2$ there are $41$ tickets in total and the chance that you win at least once is $1-\binom{39}{3}\big / \binom {41}3=0.142682927$

Comment: Note that $N\approx 41$ is very small for a lottery type game.  If we take the number nearer $10000$ the ratio of the two probabilities is almost exactly $2$, as you should expect.